# Xamarin.Forms Bottom Menu for Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I managed to show menu bar on bottom on Android. I followed this guide exactly : https://asyncawait.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/bottom-menu-for-xamarin-forms-android/#more-24

My issue is that I am working on a RTL (Right to Left) Language app, so I want to show the last tab as the default activated tab on load.
So I changed the following in PopulateChildren Method:

```
        LoadPageContent(0);
```

To:

```
        LoadPageContent(3); //I have total 4 pages (0,1,2,3)
```

Now the last page is loaded by default but the Selected color of the tab is still on the first tab. [image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [cubeupload.com](https://i.cubeupload.com/Mshssy.png))</sub>

I want to show the selected tab color on the last page. How can I do it??

Comment: Use `BottomBar.SetDefaultTabPosition(int defaultTabPosition)` to set the default position. The problem is not clear, please show more detail code.

Comment: It didn't work. I posted an answer which works. Thanks for your efforts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PopulateChildren Method in your renderer add these two lines

```
LoadPageContent(3); //This will load the 4th page
_bottomBar.SelectTabAtPosition(3, false); //This will move the bottomBar selected tab position to the 4th tab
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `CurrentPage={Your Last Page Here}` in the TabbedPage constructor.

Comment: Its not working. Nothing happens. I tried in the constructor of renderer which is MainPageRenderer